# Why does ffmpeg hardware encoding produce low quality output than software encoding?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I used this command to re-encode a video,

`ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_vaapi -b:v 1M -maxrate 1.5M output.mp4`

The resulting video has properties,

`Duration: 00:01:03.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1292 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1159 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)`

A screen shot looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65bMp.jpg)

Then I used this command that decodes the video in hardware but encode the video in software,

`ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mp4 -vf 'deinterlace_vaapi=rate=field:auto=1,hwdownload,format=nv12' -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -r 25  output.mp4`

Which results in a video of properties,

`Duration: 00:01:00.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 932 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 798 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)`

The screenshot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jAeu.jpg)

Obviously the second video has a lower bitrate but more quality. I would like to know why. I also would like to know how to achieve the second result using hardware encoding.

Comment: Hardware encoders (especially consumer-grade) are known to often sacrifice quality for speed.

Comment: What do you by mean consumer grade? Is there an another grade?

Comment: do you have a GPU which supports hardware acceleration of video processing?

Comment: Yes, the above program, I ran on my integrated graphics, I have another machine with discrete GPU, but that also falls under the category of consumer grade, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Because everything is always a compromise.

Longer answer: ASIC codecs are inevitably far less flexible and far less clever that software codecs. They are also primarily designed for high speed / low power / consistent bitrate applications such as realtime streaming where artefacts are preferable to dropped frames.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how close you will come to a good software encoder, but if your hardware supports it you can also try hevc_vaapi, which should be more efficient.

But also with h264_vaapi you shouldn't use `-b:v 1M` as this cannot give you good results, unless you specify something like **15M**.

Try `-qp 22` (and later adjust the value) or maybe even better:

`-rc_mode CQP -global_quality 22` (and adjust value later) instead.

You can also try to add `-compression_level 1` which is supposed to give better quality at lower speed.

Options are described here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#VAAPI-encoders

Might also be helpful, especially if you want to try hevc_vaapi:
https://www.tauceti.blog/posts/linux-ffmpeg-amd-5700xt-hardware-video-encoding-hevc-h265-vaapi/